# Java arraylist of arraylist - create a multi dimensional arraylist with a class object

Tags: java, class, arraylist, dynamic, processing

I'm looking to create an arraylist of arraylist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Neighbors{
ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList();
Neighbors(){}
}

ArrayList<Neighbors> outer = new ArrayList<Neighbors>();

void setup() {
size(1280, 700, JAVA2D);
background(0);

Neighbors test1 = new Neighbors();
Neighbors test2 = new Neighbors();

test1.inner.add(0);
test1.inner.add(1);
test1.inner.add(2);

test2.inner.add(5);
test2.inner.add(6);
test2.inner.add(7);

println(test1.inner);
println(test2.inner);
//  outer.add((ArrayList)test.inner);
outer.add(test1.inner);
outer.add(test2.inner);
println(outer);

}
```

This is my above code, But I could not add inner arraylist to outer arrays. I'm not sure what I'm doing is right. Or if there is any other method to do this in a right way please help.

Firstly, I'm trying to create an arraylist as objects under a class and i want to use these inner arraylist in outerarraylist. basically i need a 2d arraylist with the help of class. Please advice or help me with a sample code where i can use arraylist within arraylist, add items to it and the way to access them.

Comment: How do you want to use these arraylists together? They hold different types (`Integer` vs `Neighbor`), so you cannot just mix them. Also, it's considered poor encapsulation if you just access some class' member variables from outside that class. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: If you want a two-dimensional `ArrayList`, have you tried `ArrayList<ArrayList<some_reference_type>>`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to use these arraylists as 2d grid or matrix with dynamic memory.
Each will hold integers
for eg:

0(row) - 5 , 6 , 8, 10

1(row) - 21, 4 , 5

2(row) - 1, 4 ,5 , 5,11,12,16,.......

Comment: @LoganKulinski - Yes i did try that and it works fine. Is there any way this could be accomplished with a class and object. I really don't know how to implement it with a class. I'm open to suggestions. Please guide

Comment: You could certainly make the `ArrayList` a field. If you just want to use integers though, why a class?

Comment: Maybe to create the inner arraylist as an object so that it can be used multiple times to loop over.

Comment: @LoganKulinski
Maybe to create the inner arraylist as an object so that it can be used multiple times to loop over.
Along with the inner arraylist I'm planning to add few more flag field of array for each innerarraylist . So i would like to have them together.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
outer.add(test1.inner);
outer.add(test2.inner);
```

Do you want to use the following instead?

```
outer.add(test1);
outer.add(test2);
```

Edit: In order to print `outer`, try this.

First, add a `toString()` method to the `Neighbors` class:

```
class Neighbors {
    ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return inner.toString();
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply print `outer` using:

```
System.out.println(outer);
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to use a class, you can simply use an ArrayList of an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<>();
outer.add(new ArrayList<>());
outer.get(0).add(0);
outer.get(0).add(1);
outer.get(0).add(2);

ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<>();
inner.add(3);
inner.add(4);
outer.add(inner);

System.out.println(outer);
```

This prints out `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

Comment: Yes you are right, that works.Thank you so much. So how do i print the outer arraylist.
println(outer); - doesn;t give the arraylist instead it gives the locations

Comment: Check out my edit and let me know if it helps. If so, please mark my answer as correct. :)

Comment: Why do we have to use tostring. Is there any other way to access them. Please explain, if you don't mind can you please go through the comments of the question above and let me know whether I'm implementing it in a right way. 

I need to implement arraylist of arraylist using a class object.

Comment: By default, `toString()` for an object returns the name of the object, followed by its hash code. This is not want you want for `Neighbors` in this scenario, so you should override it and define its behavior to be what you want.

After you have done this, printing a `Neighbors` object will print out the contents of its ArrayList.

Comment: I read the comments above and this implementation of an ArrayList of an ArrayList using a class is fine.